# How to copy the contents of a .txt file to a C program as input?

Tags: c, vim, io, file-handling

The .txt file will have the matrix we need to input into our program, it may have more than one matrices.

I am using VIM editor on Linux.

Is there any specific escape sequence to copy the .txt file while compiling?

Comment: Do you want to hardcode the data or to input it dynamically?

Comment: If you just want to read a text file in to the source code of a program that you are editing in vim, type ESC then colon, then lower-case letter r, space and the path and name of the file. If you want to read the file in in the compiled program, you can do that using fopen().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect standard output to a file, the `>` character is used like this:

`ls > file_list.txt`

And To take input from the file , the `<` character is used like this:

`./a.out < input.txt`